# How to enable the RFS in Bootstrap v 4.3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

Im reading the bootstrap doc and I read this ... Bootstrap v4.3 ships with the option to enable responsive font sizes, allowing text to scale more naturally across device and viewport sizes.RFS can be enabled by changing the `$enable-responsive-font-sizes` Sass variable to `true` and recompiling Bootstrap.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/typography/#responsive-font-sizes.

My question is, how can I enable this feature, Im working on Laravel.

Comment: Laravel 5.7 ships with bootstrap 4.2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a laravel question already, but sass. Lets say you have installed bootstrap via npm in your project. Into node_modules/bootstrap folder you will find the **_variables.scss** file, there you will find the this:

```
$enable-responsive-font-sizes:                false !default;
```

Just change that value to true. Finally, if you are using laravel's `webpack.mix.js` file to compile your assets then you need to include `bootstrap.scss` and compile it:

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: I recommend to change the file resources/sass/_variables.scss that ships with laravel and run the command as @manix explained.

Comment: How would you enable RFS if your project is referencing Bootstrap using a CDN ?  I'm using the following link in my index.html file:
```<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">